# Remove last 2 digits in entire Price column of a CSV in Python, or add in a decimal before the last two digits?

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a csv that looks like this

```
Category, Item, Price, ID, New Item?
Pants,Velvet Trouser,$16800,173778,False
Pants,Tartan Flannel Skate Pant,$12800,173800,False
Pants,Studded Collars Sweatpant,$15800,173764,False
Pants,Studded Work Pant,$14800,173518,False
Pants,Regular Jean,$14800,173505,False
Pants,Rigid Slim Jean,$15800,173493,False
Pants,Stone Washed Slim Jean,$16800,173502,False
Pants,Stone Washed Black Slim Jean,$14800,173469,False
Skate,Supreme®/Spitfire® Classic Wheels (Set of 4),$3000,173533,False
Skate,Supreme®/Independent® Truck,$5000,173491,False
Skate,Pills Skateboard,$5000,173833,False
Accessories,Supreme®/Mortal Kombat by Arcade1UP,$69800,173854,True
Accessories,Christmas Stocking,$8800,173845,True
```

I need to adjust the price column and either truncate the last two zeros, or preferably add a decimal point in before the last two zeros. I cannot figure out how to do this at all.

I tried to do something like this, but it didn't take.

```
# g = csv.reader(open('Supreme_Items.csv', 'rb'))
# writer = csv.writer(open("SupremeItems.csv", 'wb'))
# for row in r:
#     row[2] = len(str(row[2])) - 2
#     # row[2] = row[2] + ".00"
#     writer.writerow(row)
```

I should mention that I created this CSV from a JSON, in case that matters.

Comment: To remove last two characters, write `row[2] = row[2][:-2]`.

Comment: It says that "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" when i try to do that, but that doesnt make sense, because I built the CSV as `f.write(item['category_name'] + "," + item['name'] + ",$" + str(item['price']) + "," + str(item['id']) + "," + str(item['new_item']) + "\n")`

Comment: Actually, that worked (stupid mistake) , but it also removed the last two characters of my column names. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `pandas`, then you can use `str.rsplit('00', n=1)` and then add '.00' to the end of the string:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.rsplit('00', n=1).str[0] + '.00'
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
df
Out[1]: 
       Category                                          Item    Price  \
0         Pants                                Velvet Trouser  $168.00   
1         Pants                     Tartan Flannel Skate Pant  $128.00   
2         Pants                     Studded Collars Sweatpant  $158.00   
3         Pants                             Studded Work Pant  $148.00   
4         Pants                                  Regular Jean  $148.00   
5         Pants                               Rigid Slim Jean  $158.00   
6         Pants                        Stone Washed Slim Jean  $168.00   
7         Pants                  Stone Washed Black Slim Jean  $148.00   
8         Skate  Supreme®/Spitfire® Classic Wheels (Set of 4)   $30.00   
9         Skate                   Supreme®/Independent® Truck   $50.00   
10        Skate                              Pills Skateboard   $50.00   
11  Accessories           Supreme®/Mortal Kombat by Arcade1UP  $698.00   
12  Accessories                            Christmas Stocking   $88.00   

        ID  New Item?  
0   173778      False  
1   173800      False  
2   173764      False  
3   173518      False  
4   173505      False  
5   173493      False  
6   173502      False  
7   173469      False  
8   173533      False  
9   173491      False  
10  173833      False  
11  173854       True  
12  173845       True
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes the magnitude and handles prices like `$99.95`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--input", help="The input file with prices having 2 orders of magnitude error.", default=None)
    parser.add_argument("--output", help="The data with corrected prices.", default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.input is None or args.output is None or args.input == args.output:
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        reader = csv.reader(open(args.input, 'rb'))
        writer = csv.writer(open(args.output, 'wb'))
        headers = None
        for row in reader:
            if headers is None:
                # First line is not processed.
                headers = row
            else:
                # get the price as float
                price = float(row[2][1:])/float(100)
                # put the price back into the row as text.
                row[2] = row[2][0] + '{:0.2f}'.format(price)
            # output the processed line.
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Example usage.

```sh
./process.py --input Supreme_Items.csv --output Supreme_Items_Prices_Corrected.csv
```

Example output.

```
Category, Item, Price, ID, New Item?
Pants,Velvet Trouser,$168.00,173778,False
Pants,Tartan Flannel Skate Pant,$128.00,173800,False
Pants,Studded Collars Sweatpant,$158.00,173764,False
Pants,Studded Work Pant,$148.00,173518,False
Pants,Regular Jean,$148.00,173505,False
Pants,Rigid Slim Jean,$158.00,173493,False
Pants,Stone Washed Slim Jean,$168.00,173502,False
Pants,Stone Washed Black Slim Jean,$148.00,173469,False
Skate,Supreme®/Spitfire® Classic Wheels (Set of 4),$30.00,173533,False
Skate,Supreme®/Independent® Truck,$50.00,173491,False
Skate,Pills Skateboard,$50.00,173833,False
Accessories,Supreme®/Mortal Kombat by Arcade1UP,$698.00,173854,True
Accessories,Christmas Stocking,$88.00,173845,True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick to the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, you can do something like this:

```py
g = csv.DictReader(open('Supreme_Items.csv', 'r'), skipinitialspace=True)
with open("SupremeItems.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=g.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in g:
        row["Price"] = row["Price"][:-2] + "." + row["Price"][-2:]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Results:

```
$cat SupremeItems.csv
Category,Item,Price,ID,New Item?
Pants,Velvet Trouser,$168.00,173778,False
Pants,Tartan Flannel Skate Pant,$128.00,173800,False
Pants,Studded Collars Sweatpant,$158.00,173764,False
Pants,Studded Work Pant,$148.00,173518,False
Pants,Regular Jean,$148.00,173505,False
Pants,Rigid Slim Jean,$158.00,173493,False
Pants,Stone Washed Slim Jean,$168.00,173502,False
Pants,Stone Washed Black Slim Jean,$148.00,173469,False
Skate,Supreme®/Spitfire® Classic Wheels (Set of 4),$30.00,173533,False
Skate,Supreme®/Independent® Truck,$50.00,173491,False
Skate,Pills Skateboard,$50.00,173833,False
Accessories,Supreme®/Mortal Kombat by Arcade1UP,$698.00,173854,True
Accessories,Christmas Stocking,$88.00,173845,True
```